# How can I implement search within more than one field in text box?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to make/create a search box.

My dream scenario would be a dynamic search box that could actually look for what is inputted with in the given table and then filter on all columns. And when the search box is empty all and any filters needs to be removed or cleaned up and that is why I have written my code within a if function.

I have been searching and watching videos for 8 days (well at night time after work) googling and searching even on different questions (with or without answers) here, it doesn't seem possible to search for more then one Field at the time? (Or is it, if so how do I archive this?)

My first field with in my table (the entire column and all the cells) will always contain numbers and this will never change, the second column will not contain anything, but when the cells have any value (usually text) I need to search for even these values. Me changing the code and liking to field 1 doesn't work at all and gives error and also since field one is just numbers the search box seem to be wanting searching on exact numbers even though I have tried to code this with wildcards.

Also what I have written so far give me errors I cant get my head around, I get 'Object is needed' on a popup window and then under the local window, 'Me' and 'WS' without actual value in under value filed/column.

The TextBox1 is of curse set on 'Change' and cell is linked to A9.

another update to the question and problem, when the Else function gets activated (this is when I remove input from box) the the table heads looses those click buttons (those that can used to manually filter/sort with), this is a massive issue and I cant understand what I'm doing to provoke this unwanted outcome.

Would apricate some help on this subject.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        If Range("A9").Value <> "" Then
                ws.ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & [A9] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            Else
                ws.ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell").Range.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: See how do I ask a good question [ask], and also edit the title and make it meaningful.

Comment: Any pointers on how I could archive a more meaningful title? I have read How to Ask but can't express myself in a better way on this so I ended up with what I wrote, English is not my native language.

Comment: How can I implement search within more than one field in text box?

Comment: I upcasted so that community can draw attention.

Comment: And I thank you for it. Really hope someone is skilled enough to help me figure this out but I'm loosing hope on this since I have been searching for so long and can't say I have even close to anyone anywhere managing either search function that works with numbers, not even one case. Also searching on more than one filed at the time. The field problem could be fixed with more than one search box of curse, one for each filed (and then this would be lees user friendly because it would require way more inputs and cleaning of the box) and then the number search which looks absolutely impossible.

Comment: My pleasure :).

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this using the `AdvancedFilter` instead. The VBA part is pretty simple (see below), and the tricky part is the criteria table setup.

You need to create a table with the number of rows and columns matching the number of columns in the Table you wanna filter. In my example, the tables has the columns `Field1`, `Field2`, ..., `Field8` (the field names must match your own Table column names). So it has 8 columns, and 9 rows (1 for the header, and 8 for the criteria).

Each row of the criteria table represents one condition for your filter. So I inserted the formula `="*" & $A$1 & "*"` (assuming this is the `LinkedCell` for the `TextBox`) for each column, but in a unique row for each column. That means it will filter when `Field1` = "*Fra*" `OR` `Field2`="*Fra*", and so on.

[image]

With the criteria table done, you just need to call the `AdvancedFilter` method in VBA, like that:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell").Range.AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("E2:L10")
        
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but cant use it so I cant say it can work for me. First, I can not specify my range, its a table and the rows very from day to day, even from one moment to another.

Comment: But what is constant is the table (columns and heders and type of information with in the cells besides the b column/field2, this will contain nothing till data is inputted and its 99% of the time text., column a/field 1 is just numbers and only numbers and this will remain so), so question,  how can Range be more dynamic and the actual table as it's and has to remain. Second, will this approach solve the need of search for numbers and not just text?

Comment: The range in CriteriaRange:=Range("E2:L10") is not the table you want to filter, is the criteria table. It won't change, and you can place it elsewhere in a different sheet if you want. The VBA code is applying the advanced filter in the table named "PR11_P3_Tabell", so it should work regardless of the number of rows.

Comment: Regarding the search for numbers, you just need to remove the asterisks from the columns that only contains numbers, i.e.: instead of ="\*" & $A$9 & "\*" just use =A9.

Comment: If I understand tis correctly, we are assuming criteria can be either this and that? Cause this is not the case here, criteria needs to, or rather has to be inputted and anything. Also I cant input this in another sheet, the file can contain one sheet, all others sheet get deleted deliberately as other part of vba cod and functions run. I cant get around this fact either.

Comment: So this is suggesting code should look like this then,

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
                ws.ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell").Range.AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
                CriteriaRange:=(A9)
Or am I not getting it?

Comment: I updated the screenshot to make it more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244165/discussion-between-ricardogerbaudo-and-assarelius).